# Is it possible to launch a file's default editor from a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt, file-association

### Background:

We can use a combination of `PATHEXT` and the Windows file associations to do the **Command Prompt** equivalent of right-clicking a file in **Explorer** and clicking **Open**, e.g.:

```
C:\code\python> echo print "Hello, StackOverflow!" >hello.py

C:\code\python> hello
Hello, StackOverflow!
```

Similarly, I could use this to launch **Photoshop** by typing:

```
C:\art\source> StackOverflowLogo.PDF
```

### The Actual Problem:

I need the command prompt equivalent of right-clicking the file in Explorer and selecting **Edit** instead.

With my hello(.py) above, that would likely bring up Python's **Idle** editor.  However, I need a universal solution that uses the OS-level association for the file type.  I can't assume it.

The simplest possible example of what I'd like to do would be this hypothetical EDIT.BAT file, which would do nothing but launch the editor for the given filename:

```
@InsertMagic /Here %1
```

Thanks!  (I hope.)

---

### *Aaand*... the solution:

Alex K. suggests Powershell, which is of course a great solution.  So to write my EDIT.BAT above, I could do this:

```
@powershell -command "start -verb edit '%1'"
```

(That's slightly naïve, since there are potential quoting issues, but you get the idea.)

Cheers for the speedy answer.  :)

Comment: I would use `%~1` as that removes surrounding quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those items on the right-click menu are called *Shell **Verbs***, they can be invoked by name for a target file but not with any direct batch or windows command.

Win7/2k8r2 upwards you can use PowerShell to do it from your batch file:

```
powershell -command "start -verb edit 'C:\art\source\StackOverflowLogo.PDF'"
```

Comment: Ah, Powershell, of course!  That totally works.  Cheers!

Comment: Actually, I have a follow-up.  Is there any way to fire off the edit verb on a non-existent file?  Seems that 'start', and its underlying ShellExecuteEx() call, require an existing file, so one cannot say "edit somenewfile.txt" and get notepad popping up with "Eh, this doesn't exist, shall we make a new one then?"  Instead the ps1 script just barfs with "start : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified."  It's not a big deal, just curious if you know a workaround.  The new-item verb just creates 0-length file and exits, so that's a dead end.  :/

Comment: Interesting! Isn't powershell invoke the standard `start` cmd.exe command this way? If so, then should be a way of do the same thing from the command-line!

Comment: Nope; its an abbreviated form of `start-process`

Comment: Likely the only workaround would be to create an empty file then open it

Comment: Also, this isn't universal given the target application must have registered its ability to understand the Edit verb.