# Opening a Ruby program's source file in the default editor

Tags: ruby, windows

In Ruby on Windows 7, how do you open a program's source file from the command line?

Example:

```
def dev_mode
  if ARGV[0] == '--dev-mode'
    system('open test.rb')
  end
end
```

Is it possible to open a program using the default editor of the user's computer? Such as opening it in notepad (if the user doesn't have an editor) or the editor the user uses for source files?

Comment: Which operating system are you asking about?  Calling `open` is a Mac convention, but Notepad is a standard windows application - on Mac, the equivalent application is TextEdit.app.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill I totally thought I added the OS, I apologize, it's Windows 7, and has been added to the question

Comment: This looks useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36011597/is-it-possible-to-launch-a-files-default-editor-from-a-batch-file

Comment: @Jordan Wow, that's a good one, but that completely changes my question lol. Thank you though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical way to open a file with the associated program is different from one operating system (or shell) to another.  Here are 4 examples that will work on the specified OSes:

## Opening the File

### Windows

Use the standard command shell `start`, available beginning with Windows 95:

```
system %{cmd /c "start #{file_to_open}"}
```

### Mac OS X

Use the standard `open` command:

```
system %{open "#{file_to_open}"}
```

### Linux/Unix Gnome

Use the Gnome utility `gnome-open`:

```
system %{gnome-open "#{file_to_open}"}
```

### Linux/Unix

Use the `xdg-open` utility:

```
system %{xdg-open "#{file_to_open}"}
```

## Associated Programs

Detecting the associated program for a file type can be a fairly tall order on any one system.  For instance, with Windows, you have to inspect the registry, whereas with Mac OS X you have to read the right plist values; Linux is a whole other world, altogether.

You're likely better off simply requiring the user to have a program associated to make things easy enough to get started.  Once you have the other logic working in your application, you might be able to add interesting features like fallback to a default application in the absence of an existing file association.

Comment: This: `system %{cmd /c "start #{file_to_open}"}` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Did you either assign a value to the `file_to_open` variable or replace the `#{file_to_open}` with a filename, such as "test.rb"?  You also have to already have the file association for that file type established prior to running the `cmd /c "start .."`call.

Comment: Here's a short article on the Windows `start` command with `cmd /c`: [Open a File in the Default Application Using the Windows Command Line](http://www.frankworsley.com/blog/2007/9/24/open-a-file-in-the-default-application-using-the-windows-command-line-without-jdic)

Comment: Note that opening a file with the associated program isn't the same as opening a file with the default editor. If you just want to open files with the associated program, take a look at the [opener](https://github.com/sunaku/opener) gem.

Comment: I user `$PROGRAM_NAME` which should assign the value as the default name of the file being urn at that moment.

Comment: @13aal Can you show exactly what you tried, with quotes and everything?

Comment: `system %{cmd /c "start #{$PROGRAM_NAME}"}`

Comment: Have you verified the value of $PROGRAM_NAME in your case?  If you `puts "$PROGRAM_NAME: #{$PROGRAM_NAME}"` in place of the system call, what do you get?

Comment: That name of the program..? What else would I get?

Comment: Just making sure that you get the right thing.  I'm running it and it's working fine, but it seems to do nothing for you.  I thought maybe there was something conflicting on your system.  If I run `ruby progname.rb` and progname.rb contains `system %{cmd /c "start #{$PROGRAM_NAME}"}`, it attempts to open `progname,rb` with the system file association.  I simply don't know why it's not working on your system.

Answer (score 2):

On a Mac, you're already halfway there; `open` opens a file in the default application. By default it opens a reasonable editor for text files and XCode for Ruby files; I don't edit Ruby in XCode, but I could change the association if I wanted.

The name of the file that started a Ruby program is in `$PROGRAM_NAME`, so you can do

```
def dev_mode
  if ARGV[0] == '--dev-mode'
    system("open #{$PROGRAM_NAME}")
  end
end
```

On Unix-like systems, including OS X, you might want to use the value of `ENV['EDITOR']` (the `EDITOR` environment variable) if it's set. That's a convention used by many programs.

I'll let others give answers for other operating systems.

Comment: I revised my answer while you were commenting; see if it answers that question now.

Comment: Awh okay, sorry for the impatience, so basically it will open in the editor that the OS defaults to when opening source files?

Comment: More or less. OS X maps file suffixes to applications which might be editors or might be viewers or something else. Its defaults for .txt and .rb are editors, but for .html it opens a browser and for .pdf and image extensions it opens Preview.

Comment: That's very interesting, thanks for the great answer!